# Caliburn.Micro: Bind text of a button that is already bound by convention to a method

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.Micro's excellent convention-based binding to bind a button to a method on my view model. Thing is, I want the `Content` of the button to be bound to a `string` property of the view model.

At the moment I'm allowing the convention binding for the method, and an explicit binding for the content. Here's an example:

E.g.:

```
<Button x:Name="Submit" Content="{Binding SubmitCaption}" />

public class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public void Submit() {}
    public string SubmitCaption { get; set; } // Technically would raise PropertyChanged event
}
```

However I was wondering if there's there a more elegant way of doing this? I'm thinking about overriding the convention for buttons so that it still binds the button action to a method but the content to a named-by-convention property.

```
<Button x:Name="Submit" />

public class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public void Submit() {}
    public string SubmitContent { get; set; } // Technically would raise PropertyChanged event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could customise the default behaviour for all buttons, but I think your current approach is more explicit and obvious to developers, and doesn't seem particularly nasty. I would recommend sticking with what you've got.

What happens if you decide you want the `Button` content to be more than a string? Do you make `SubmitContent` an object type? Would you set its value in code? That sounds nastier to me.

Comment: I was thinking it's not much different to binding the button's `Enabled` property to `CanSubmit()` by convention, though. I don't think there's a problem having the `SubmitContent` being a string - it's just a binding. It could be anything, but it'd only be a string. Yes, I'd be setting that string value in code, but that's what viewmodels are for, so I reckon it's okay.

Comment: Yes, setting strings is fine, I was wondering what would happen if you wanted more complex Button contents. If you're sure that this is going to be really beneficial to you, and not confusing to other developers, who don't have your implied knowledge, then you can customise the conventions. Are you asking how you would go about doing this? Because the way the question is phrased, it sounds like you were just asking for some feedback on the usefulness of the idea?